# passing varibel with onchange function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script for show/hide divs

```
var folder;
$(function() {
    $('#teamleag').change(function() {
        if ($('#teamleag').val() == 'footballal') {
            $('#selectleag').show();
            $('#selectleag1').hide();
            $('#selectleag2').hide();
            folder = "basket";
        } else if ($('#teamleag').val() == 'footballleomit') {
            $('#selectleag').hide();
            $('#selectleag1').show();
            $('#selectleag2').hide();
            folder = "footballal";
        } else if ($('#teamleag').val() == 'basketball') {
            $('#selectleag').hide();
            $('#selectleag1').hide();
            $('#selectleag2').show();
            folder = "football_leomit";
        }

    });
});
```

Inside the div I have select option tag that show image when selected

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#hometeam").change(function() {
        var src = $(this).val();
        $("#imagePreview").html(src ? '<img class=home src="img/teamslogo/' + folder + '/' + src + '">' : '');
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#awayteam").change(function() {
        var src = $(this).val();
        $("#imagePreview1").html(src ? '<img class=home src="img/teamslogo/' + folder + '/' + src + '">' : '');
    });
});
```

The images are coming from different folders. How can I pass a variable with the folder name and link it to the div selected. I tried to put folder global variable and pass it between them but I get `undefined`

Answer (score -1):

Take hidden field like below

`<input id="folderName" type="hidden" value="">`

```
$(function() {
    $('#teamleag').change(function() {
        if ($('#teamleag').val() == 'footballal') {
            $('#selectleag').show();
            $('#selectleag1').hide();
            $('#selectleag2').hide();
            $('#folderName').val('basket');
        } else if ($('#teamleag').val() == 'footballleomit') {
            $('#selectleag').hide();
            $('#selectleag1').show();
            $('#selectleag2').hide();
            $('#folderName').val('footballal');
        } else if ($('#teamleag').val() == 'basketball') {
            $('#selectleag').hide();
            $('#selectleag1').hide();
            $('#selectleag2').show();
            $('#folderName').val('football_leomit');
        }

    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#awayteam").change(function() {
        var src = $(this).val();
        var folder = $("#folderName").val();
        $("#imagePreview1").html(src ? '<img class="home" src="img/teamslogo/' + folder + '/' + src + '">' : '');
    });
});
```

Hope this code work fine ....